# Can a Sith Warrior or Inquisitor wear the Mask of Revan?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

On Star Wars:The Old Republic I was playing as my Bounty Hunter. I was sent to retrieve the Mask of Revan. I wanted to keep the mask for myself but found it not in my inventory so I gave the mask to one of the Revanites.

Is this because I'm playing a Bounty Hunter? 
Can one of the force-using classes, such as the Sith Warrior or Inquisitor equip it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Mask of Revan is a quest item for the mission you are on to retrieve it, from the Revanite camp on Dromund Kaas.  That means it gets put on a different tab on your inventory, and would not function as a piece of your equipment no matter what class you were.

Answer (score -2):

Your not allowed yo keep the mask no matter what you choose it never will become a useable headgear or mask. Just a quest item. Pick your path lol.

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything that isn't covered in the accepted answer. Duplicate answers are discouraged and may be subject to deletion.